# Why is velocity of outermost point on a rotating wheel double the velocity of centre of mass?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

'In the answers to one of the questions based on rotation of a disc in my physics book the answer includes the statement 'As we know that the velocity of outermost point on a rotating disc is double the velocity of center of mass'. But, I didn't know that and why is it like that?

My thinking: I know that as we go away from the center of mass the tangential velocity of particles of the disc increases according to $v=wr$. But, how does that result in the above result?

Comment: I guess, the disk is rolling on the surface (like the wheel), in which case the velocity of the upper point of the disk relative to the ground is twice the velocity of the center.

Comment: But relative to center of mass the velocity should be v, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you start in the rest frame of the wheel the velocities of the top and bottom points are $v$ and $-v$, and the velocity of the centre of mass (black dot) is of course zero because that's how we define the rest frame.

[image: Wheel]

If this wheel is on a moving vehicle the velocity of the bottom must be zero, because it's in contact with the stationary road. To make the bottom velocity zero we add a velocity of $v$ to the rest frame. That makes the bottom velocity zero, the top velocity $2v$ and the centre of mass velocity $v$. Hence the velocity of the top point is twice the velocity of the centre of mass.

At least, I assume that's what your physics book means. I'm also assuming the wheel is symmetrical so the centre of mass is in the middle i.e. the wheel isn't on a clown's car at the circus!